# Type mismatch in for loop, Scala

Tags: scala

I'm running into a persistand error.

```
var pageArray = new Array[ImageIcon](tempDir.size)
for (page <- tempDir.toList) {
    pageArray += new ImageIcon(page.getAbsolutePath)
}
Some(new Pages(pageArray)) //returns class with constructor Array[ImageIcon]
```

When I try to compile, this block of code produces a type mismatch error:

```
Error:(43, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : javax.swing.ImageIcon
 required: String
                pageArray += new ImageIcon(page.getAbsolutePath)
                             ^
```

I don't understand where it's getting String from, and when I try this code:

```
var pageArray = new Array[ImageIcon](tempDir.size)
for (page <- tempDir.toList) {
    pageArray += "test" //new ImageIcon(page.getAbsolutePath)
}
Some(new Pages(pageArray)) //returns class with constructor Array[ImageIcon]
```

I get the following:

```
Error:(43, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Array[javax.swing.ImageIcon]
                pageArray += "test"//new ImageIcon(page.getAbsolutePath)
                          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `+=` is not the right operator to use - to append a value to an array you can use `:+`:

```
scala> var intArray = new Array[Int](4)
intArray: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> intArray :+ 5
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 5)
```

Second, as you can see in the example above, it doesn't make much sense to create the array with size `tempDir.size` and then *append* to it - you'll end up with an array with size `2 * tempDir.size`.

A better implementation of what I assume you're trying to do would be:

```
tempDir.map(page => new ImageIcon(page.getAbsolutePath)).toArray
```

Which would simply create a new Array with each of the original collection's values mapped using the anonymous function provided. When using Scala collections, it is often recommended to look for such higher-order functions instead of iterating over the collection and updating a mutable collection.

Now, as for where this `String` is coming from: since scala.Array does not have a `+=` operator, the compiler looks for an implicit conversion into something that does. It finds this:

```
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](self : A) extends scala.AnyVal  {
  def +(other : scala.Predef.String) : scala.Predef.String = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

which calls the `self.toString` and then appends the value on the right-hand side, expecting it to be a String.

Comment: Wouldn't we be saving an `Array` allocation if we called `toArray` after `map`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov correct! Although I have no idea what type `tempDir` has to begin with - might actually be an Array... anyway, thanks - fixed.